# Convert string value read from file to ASCII in python

Tags: python, hex, ascii

I will describe my problem in details:

First I'm reading some values from a CSV file as:

```
def import_csv(my_csv_file):
  with open(my_file, mode='r') as infile:
    reader = csv.reader(infile)
    next(reader) # Ignore the first row
    return dict((rows[0]+struct.pack('!L',int(rows[1])), [rows[2],rows[3]]) for rows in reader)
```

Then I call this function as:

```
DB = import_csv(my_csv_file)
```

Each line in my_csv_file has the format:

40.1.1.2,1,\x00123,bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb

After importing I get one element of the dict as:

```
value = DB['40.1.1.2\x00\x00\x00\x01'][0]
```

But now I need to convert **value** (which contains the string \x00123) to its ASCII equivalent where any two characters prefixed with \x represent a HEX value. That is, for the example above, I want

\x00123 = 00313233

I have tried with the binascii.hexlify command but that gives me the ASCII equivalent of **each character** in the read string, i.e.:

binascii.hexlify(value) = 5c783030313233

If instead I do:

```
value_0 = '\x00123'
print binascii.hexlify(value_0)
```

I get the desired result, i.e., 00313233. So it seems that after reading the value from the file, the hex escape character \x is considered as values in the string. Note that the point of including e.g. the \x00 part is to include non-printable characters in the value I will read from the file.

Is there any way to do what I want? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not add the conversion when creating the dictionary? Use `decode('string_escape')` to process any `\x`, and then `.encode('hex')` to convert it back into hex:

```
import csv
import struct

def import_csv(my_csv_file):
  with open(my_csv_file, mode='rb') as infile:
    reader = csv.reader(infile)
    next(reader) # Ignore the first row
    return dict((row[0] + struct.pack('!L', int(row[1])), [row[2].decode('string_escape').encode('hex'), row[3]]) for row in reader)

DB = import_csv('input.csv')

value = DB['40.1.1.2\x00\x00\x00\x01'][0]
print value
```

This would display:

```
00313233
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. However, what I want is for the \x00123 to show as 00313233, that is, \x00 = 0x00, 1 = 0x31, 2 = 0x32, 3 = 0x33. To give you another example of what I want, If the value read from the file was 12\x003 then I would like it to be translated as 31320033, i.e., 1 = 0x31, 2 = 0x32, \x00 = 0x00, 3 = 0x33. So if two characters are preceded by \x, then it should be interpreted as a hex number, not to be translated to ASCII. That is exactly what binascii.hexlify does but it doesn't seem to work if the value is read from an external file.

Comment: I see, in that case use `.decode('string_escape')`. I have updated the script.